# Synchronous event triggering

Tags: scala, synchronization, akka, eventtrigger

I want to trigger at the exact same time through `message` receipt, some processes into different `Actor`s. Considering my `Actor`s possible heavily stacked `mailBox`es, what would be the best method to implement this?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to send the messages at the same time? Or do you want a guarantee that the actors will read the messages at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the actors to read the messages at the same time. This, of course is not possible (while an actor is processing a message he cannot be disturbed).

But you can make sure that your trigger message is the next message they will take from the mailbox. This can be achieved by using a priority mailbox, for example this one: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/index.html#akka.dispatch.UnboundedStablePriorityMailbox

The messages in the mailbox will be sorted by priority. If you give your trigger messages the highest priority, they will be processed first.

Comment: Thank you. I'm thinking on using `UnboundedControlAwareMailbox` (http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/index.html#akka.dispatch.UnboundedControlAwareMailbox)